Manager and Team Lead are doing same work
I have an IT Manager and Team Lead who work in an MSP. I see both the Manager and Lead doing the same work. All the work I give to the Manager, the Manager delegates to the Team Lead, and the Manager sends a report to me that the Team lead has provided, I have to review the report and the Manager is not doing it. The manager presents data in front of the customer without understanding the gaps in the data provided by the Team lead.
How to ensure the Manager understands that he can not delegate all work to the Team lead.

What is your role?

Is the manager doing what they are supposed to doing? What is their job description and how is it different from the team lead?

I am assuming that you are in a position of authority over said Manager and TL - in which case - it should be as simple as making sure the instruction is clear e.g.

Because you are going to be presenting this in front of the customer, I would like you to generate the report. Please do not delegate this to name of TL

However - I think there are some wider issues here.
1: Managers should be delegating work to their subordinates, in most cases. That is to say - a Managers job is to... manage - Certainly administrative functions cannot usually be delegated.
2: It seems the issue here is not who generates the report - the underlying issue is that the person who presents the report in front of the customer does not have sufficient understanding.
And this is where I really want to dig into the question:
If the Team Lead is generating the report, why are they not the one to present it to the customer?
Certainly a TL position is usually senior enough to be entrusted with handling customer-facing tasks, such as leading a meeting, or at least presenting a particular section of the meeting.
But let us for the sake of argument say that the TL doesn't want to present or feels uncomfortable presenting or any N number of legitimate reasons why they might not present:
The issue is not who prepared the report, the issue is that the person presenting the report did not properly prep and familiarize themselves with the data and the detail
And this is where I would focus my efforts - Whilst it is true that generating a report gives you a certain degree of insight or understanding of the nuance and limitations, by the very nature of doing it yourself (and it may be that the realities of the report mean that you need the person who presents it, to be the person who creates it) - it is not necessarily true.
The conversation I would be having with the manager would be to talk about this aspect - that they are not doing enough prep work to understand all the relevant detail(s) before presenting to the customer.
